# Why do tests time out after converting a Flux store to a reducer?

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, react-redux

I'm trying to get started with moving from a Flux implementation (McFly) to Redux.

As start, I'm refactoring a Flux store to handle actions via a reducer: https://github.com/WikiEducationFoundation/WikiEduDashboard/commit/f979e6fc04ba57209c107beff2440bc0baa052f3

This seems to work fine with manual testing, but this change causes the javascript test suite (mocha) grinds to a halt about halfway through (both locally and on travis-ci).

What has gone wrong?